# Retrieving GPS EXIF data from images using AndroidX ExifInterface?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, runtime-permissions, android-exifinterface, photo-picker

I'm targeting Android 13 and using the [new photo picker](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared/photopicker) to retrieve images. E.g.

```
val photoPicker = rememberLauncherForActivityResult(
        contract = ActivityResultContracts.PickMultipleVisualMedia()
    ) { uris: List<Uri> -> handleUris(context, uris) ) }) }

photoPicker.launch(PickVisualMediaRequest(ActivityResultContracts.PickVisualMedia.ImageOnly))

fun handleUris(context: Context, uris: List<Uri>) {
    for (uri in uris) {
        context.contentResolver.openInputStream(uri)!!.use { stream ->
            ExifInterface(stream).let { exif ->
                val dateTime = exif.dateTime // present
                val latLng = exif.latLong // always null
            }
        }
    }
}
```

What i've found:

Since Android 10 GPS information is not included anymore in the EXIF data when you retrieve media. According to this [video](https://youtu.be/UnJ3amzJM94?t=803) from 2019 you need to request the runtime permission `ACCESS_MEDIA_LOCATION`.

They explain that it is a runtime permission but the user cannot see the permission in the system settings (which by itself is quite bizarre).
They also claim you need the `READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` alongside the media permission.

[This piece of documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared/media#media-location-permission) talks about the media location permission as well.

Requesting the `ACCESS_MEDIA_LOCATION` permission using:

```
val locationPermissionState = rememberPermissionState(
        permission = ACCESS_MEDIA_LOCATION
)
locationPermissionState.launchPermissionRequest()
```

It actually does result in a permission dialog asking for "App to access photos and videos on this device". When granted the EXIF location data is still not present though.

Ah, right. According to the video we need the `READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` as well.

```
val locationPermissionState = rememberMultiplePermissionsState(
        permissions = listOf(ACCESS_MEDIA_LOCATION, READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
)
```

No dialog is shown.. checking with `ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission()` it appears we have the `ACCESS_MEDIA_LOCATION` permission, but no `READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE`. Why doesn't it show a dialog for it?

Looking at the [docs for Android 13](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/13/behavior-changes-13#granular-media-permissions) it seems that `READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` is replaced with more granular permissions.

It appears when targeting Android 13 you should not use the `READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE`  permission anymore. For images we need `READ_MEDIA_IMAGES` instead. But requesting that permission does not show a dialog either.

I have also tried the `MediaStore.setRequireOriginal(Uri)` API which should prevent the EXIF metadata to be redacted, according to the [docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/MediaStore#setRequireOriginal(android.net.Uri)) this throws an `UnsupportedOperationException` when you don't have the `ACCESS_MEDIA_LOCATION`
permission. But for me it throws an `SecurityException` with the message `Calling uid does not have permission to access picker uri: content://etc`.

So yeah, how do I get the GPS location in the EXIF data; what permissions do I actually need and how do I request them?

EDIT:

Ok, so on Android 11 when the photo picker is not available, it uses `Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT)` internally instead. The Uri that is returned from that looks like this: `content://com.android.providers.media.documents/document/image%3A283`

I am able to retrieve GPS position from that uri WITHOUT having granted `ACCESS_MEDIA_LOCATION`, `READ_MEDIA_IMAGE` or `READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permissions. In contrary to most of the documentation I could find. Also no `MediaStore.setRequireOriginal(Uri)` is needed.

Which makes me think it is a photo picker issue instead of a permissions issue. So I figured I test on Android 13 without using the photo picker.

I'm using

```
val photoPicker = rememberLauncherForActivityResult(
    contract = ActivityResultContracts.GetContent()
) { uri: Uri? ->  }
```

Instead now, which uses `Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT)` internally.
The uri looks like this `content://com.android.providers.media.documents/document/image%3A1000000049` and again I am able to pull GPS data without having any aforementioned permissions granted and no `setRequireOriginal`.

Which leaves me to conclude that the [docs](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared/media#media-location-permission) about media location are wrong.. the permission is not needed (unless they are talking about other metadata than latitude/longitude). And there must be something going on with the new photo picker uri's resulting in `SecurityException` when using `setRequireOriginal` and/or exif data redaction. Whether that is expected behaviour, I do not know yet.

Comment: Think that you need MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission.

Comment: Already needed for Android 11.

Comment: MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE is reserved for apps like file managers and need explicit permission from Google when published to Google Play, isn't it?

Comment: It also seems like overkill since I already have access to the image, only the exif location is missing.

Comment: Yes. But you could just try it to know.

Comment: You need location permission too maybe. Just try.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As of now location metadata is redacted from the images retrieved via the new photo picker. It might get added in the future but for now we're stuck with the "old" `Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT`.

Please star [this issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/243294058).